# Parallel computation in Julia

Tags: parallel-processing, scope, julia

I'm working with a code in Julia and I'm using parallel computation. Here it is the function I'm using (which is simplified from the real one).

I'm trying to evaluate what I called the "Hitting Time":

```
using Distributed
using LinearAlgebra


function action(Ntraj::Int64,  
    Tfinal::Float64,                   
    dt::Float64)                
        
    
    # Output time vector
    t = (1 : Ntime) * dt
    
    #Vectors of Hitting Times
    HittingTime = zeros(Ntraj)

    @distributed for ktraj = 1 : Ntraj

        
    HittingTimeBool = false
    

    for jt=1:Ntime
               

            
            if (HittingTimeBool == false && jt >0.1)
                HittingTimeBool=true
                HittingTime[ktraj] = jt*dt
                println(HittingTime[ktraj])
            end
    end
    end
    println(HittingTime)
    return (HittingTime)
end
```

So I run the function for 5 Trajectories (just to try to see what happens) and these that follows are the results

```
using Distributed
addprocs(4)

@everywhere include("untitled.jl")

(t, Fid, HittingTime) = @time action(5,10.,0.01);
      From worker 2:    0.01
      From worker 5:    0.01
      From worker 3:    0.01
      From worker 4:    0.01
      From worker 6:    0.01
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
  0.723837 seconds (121.59 k allocations: 6.331 MiB)
HittingTime
5-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
```

As you can see, in the for cycle the function enters the if and the value of `HittingTime[ktraj] = jt*dt` is stored. But when the for cycle ends, the values in the HittingTime array seems to disappear! I cannot use the hcat as for the `FidelitytoTarget` since the arrays have different dimensions, so how can I write some code to store these values?

Comment: Now since you know the answer, please simplify your question to make it readable and useable for others.

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel I did simplify the question, as you suggested. i think now is clearer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a `SharedArray` to mutate the state across the workers.

```
using Distributed, SharedArrays
addprocs(4)
HittingTime=SharedArray{Float64}(nworkers())

res = @distributed (+) for i in 1:length(HittingTime)
    HittingTime[i] = rand()
    HittingTime[i]
end

@assert res ≈ sum(HittingTime)
```

Comment: Or multithreading instead of multiprocessing

Comment: Yes as long as there is no more than around 16 threads. For huge scale jobs multiprocessing (or distributed computing) turns out to be better option.